# Serial port incompatible with monitor

Tags: display, desktop-computer, external-display, serial-port, analog

This question is similar to:

[Will a VGA monitor work if connected to 9-pin serial port?](https://superuser.com/questions/386359/will-a-vga-monitor-work-if-connected-to-9-pin-serial-port)

Can this workstation be used with modern serial monitors?

[image]

The blue serial port has a box with "10101" in it.

Comment: Why not just use the DVI right next to it, or above that, what looks very much like an HDMI port?

Comment: Good point :P I'll need an adapter.

Comment: Check the mobo spec to see if that's a DVI-A compatible, or just DVI-D. You can't always tell by looking at the socket [often they'll use a DVI-I socket whatever the actual capability . If it's D only, you'll need a more expensive adapter. A-compatible is a simple cable. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Visual_Interface

Comment: Note 2: By the time you've paid for an expensive DVI-D adaptor, you could have bought a cheap 2nd hand HDMI or DVI-D capable screen, which would probably be far more energy-efficient, saving even more in the long run.