# Can a VGA monitor be connected to parallel port?

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, hdmi, vga, dvi

I have an old system that I want to connect two monitors with. I have only one VGA port, a parallel port and a 9-pin serial port on the system. One of the monitor only has a VGA port while the other one has a VGA as well as a DVI port. From this [question](https://superuser.com/questions/386359/will-a-vga-monitor-work-if-connected-to-9-pin-serial-port), I know that I cannot use the 9-pin serial connector. How can I connect two monitor to this system, can I use a "VGA to parallel adapter" (?) to connect the two monitors?

Comment: The parallel port electronics would be far too slow to be able to drive a VGA signal at any speed that would allow a good display.

Comment: Parallel to VGA adapters do not exist. Maybe there could be one having 1 frame per minute or so.

Comment: What kind of _internal_ ports does the system have? If it's a desktop, does it have any spare PCI/ISA/AGP slots?

Comment: Hypothetically - I wonder if you could use something to 'convert' a monitor to an old school serial console.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek That sounds like a good use for an older raspberry pi that we all have laying about somewhere.

Comment: VGA is *analog* while the parallel port is digital. The "adapter" would have to be effectively a parallel-port-connected GPU, and I don't think those exist. If you just want two copies of the same output image e.g. for presentation purposes, there are "VGA signal splitters" for that.

Comment: The answers also make me wonder - how *old* a system is this?

Comment: @zomega: A parallel port can potentially do [2.5Mbyte/s](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_1284). Basic VGA is 640x480, 4bits/pixel - or 150Kbytes. So even if you send every pixel, every frame (which you wouldn't necessarily need to), you can get about 16 frames/second, which is pretty acceptable for some use cases.

Comment: @psmears a monitor doesn’t know about the graphic card’s builtin colors. So you can’t assume 4bits/pixel. Unless you consider pure monochrome (1bit/pixel), you have to transfer the full color information for each pixel. Or you don’t have an adapter but an actual external graphics card.

Comment: @Holger: I'm not sure where the line is between "an adapter" and an "actual external graphics card" - there are certainly many things sold as "USB to VGA adapter" that basically implement a graphics card in the adapter itself. And other considerations mean that - if you _really_ wanted to do this for some reason - you'd probably end up with something quite like a graphics card. But that aside, a look-up table for the palette, either in ROM or even in SRAM (with the palette contents sent once per frame) isn't hard to implement and would barely affect the refresh rate.

Comment: @psmears if your “adapter” has external memory, there’s no point in discussing required transfer rates, as you can have the entire buffer outside the old PC and only transfer data over the parallel port when something changes, which can be as slow as you want and still have reasonable refresh rates… But you’re right, nowadays things are sold as “adapter” which are far more than an adapter.

Comment: @Holger:That's not true, because even with external memory you'd be limited as to how often you could update the whole screen. Not an issue for, say, a text display where most of the screen is static most of the time, but for a Doom-like game (not that the PC in question could likely run one well!) that could be problematic. But in any case, the original comment I was responding to claimed "1 frame per minute"; even if you transferred 18 bits/pixel ([enough for VGA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_16-bit_computer_color_palettes#MCGA_and_VGA)) you could get multiple frames per _second_!

Comment: @psmears I don’t think that 640x480x16 colors would be the reference for Doom-like games. On the other hand, with the 320×200 mode, you could indeed get playable refresh rates, even with 18 bits/pixel, if we assume that CPU and memory can keep up with this theoretical parallel port bandwidth. The “1 frame per minute” was way too pessimistic (I misread “1 frame per second” when I read it the first time, as apparently my brain did already assume a different order of magnitude).

Comment: @Holger: Agreed, we all know that the reference for Doom-like games is [80x25 text mode](https://doomwiki.org/wiki/Text_Mode_Doom)!

Comment: Obligatory xkcd: https://xkcd.com/478/

Comment: Presumably you need a graphics card capable of two monitors, an extra graphics card, or an extra computer. (Do not assume that your obviously-very-old computer *can* have two graphics cards in it)

Comment: What research, if any, did you do before posting this question? Or to be more blunt: why would you ever think this could work?

Comment: ***BIG*** XY problem.  Any electronics that old should be regarded as ready to die at literally any second.  If you want to do any serious work with software on that PC, your actual solution is to migrate that software to a new PC.  Maybe use a VM if it doesn't work with current Windows, but however you go about it, you need to abandon ship on that PC ASAP.

Comment: While other answers are basically correct, it's worth mentioning that _text mode_ display on a VGA via parallel-to-serial adapter connected to a terminal adapter is possible.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Unfortunately, no.  You would not be able to connect a monitor to a parallel port.  They were designed for slow devices, like printers, scanners, etc.  Not to mention it would require special device drivers.  The easiest method of connecting another monitor to your computer would be to add a graphics card that supports two video outputs or put in a second video card.  Alternatively, you can use a DVI or VGA to USB adapter.  Those absolutely work.  However, if the port is USB 2, you could use it for regular desktop use (email, word processing, spreadsheets, etc), but not video playback or gaming, as it would be too slow and choppy.  USB 3 is fine, but it the machine is old, its doubtful you have it.  If you only have USB 1 or 1.1, then I wouldnt try it.

Comment: I wouldn’t expect the OP’s computer to have USB at all…

Comment: @Holger we only know it's got VGA and parallel, we don't know anything else. Loads of machines had VGA, parallel, and USB1 with no HDMI/DVI so it's reasonably likely to have useless USB

Comment: @ChrisH The OP did state: "I have **only** one VGA port, a parallel port and a 9-pin serial port on the system"

Comment: @MrWhite, but does "only" apply to the whole list, or does it just mean that there's only one VGA port? I read it as the latter, partly because we all know the list isn't exhaustive (there's bound to be some form of keyboard port, and almost certainly either a 2nd serial port or more likely a PS/2 mouse port)

Comment: I used a USB 2.0 to DVI adapter for a couple years and was surprised at how well it performed. No gaming sure, but web browsing, even video, was okay. YMMV

Comment: I worked with computers extensively around this period (Windows 95/98/ME/XP/2000), and USB is unlikely to be 2.0. It is still possible though, since parallel is technically still available until the XP/2000 era, and USB2.0 was introduced around this time also.

Comment: not sure why there is a discussion, we have no idea what age computer he has, or exactly what is available.

Comment: @Nelson I've had a parallel port on XP--needed to talk to an industrial printer.

Answer (score 15):

Parallel?  No not without a lot of skill and patience and a probably-still suboptimal result.   Parallel is just too slow for graphics.

A serial console on the other hand, can present text characters in a far more useful way.  You could hide an older rasperry pi around the back of your monitor and run a USB/serial cable from that to your main front PC. Then set the Pi to boot linux, run a serial terminal like minicom on boot, and get your main machine to run a `getty` on its own serial port.

Pi's have HDMI, and you can get a HDMI-DVI cable to make the monitor connection easy.

---

You can also put a Hercules or MDA card in the box with your VGA card, and have a second display.  You might choose to have the second montior as a logging console in linux, or a second terminal, or even run its own X server.    Useful links at https://www.seasip.info/VintagePC/dualhead.html

---

A third option is to consider what you want to do - some software supports multihead output using a remote client accessed via a network.  Classic examples include Doom 1.1 with its `-left` and `-right` parameters,

[image]
<sub>from https://www.techeblog.com/doom-1-1-multi-monitor-setup/</sub>

or the famous MS Flight Simulator  from 2002, which is over 20 years ago.

[image]

---

Downside - all these depend on some additional hardware from what you describe, and most require more computers, power, and space while adding complexity.

Some very-few video cards of the "old" era may support multiple monitor natively.  I had three displays on one linux host in around 2005, using one AGP and one PCI NVidia card which worked well.   Finding suitable video cards may be your shortest path to success, but the OS will play a big part too.

Comment: You can also run a VGA monitor of a Raspberry Pi with an HDMI-VGA adaptor cable.  It's a good way of using up old VGA-only monitors for equipment that needs its own console, but only occasionally. I had student setups that were mainly logging, for example.  These active adaptors were cheaper than HDMI-DVI passive cables!

Comment: Awesome gaming setups! (Now let's pack it for the LAN party ;-).)

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica that the last one was from a FILM CAMERA shows just how long ago it all was.   (neither are my photos btw)    21 years... there are mods on SE who are younger than that photo.

Comment: Certainly, neither Doom nor Flight Simulator sent the video signal over the network. They just sent some player data and the PCs then rendered the view accordingly. Not sure if that's a fair comparison to what OP wants.

Comment: @ThomasWeller you are correct there - OP hasn't told us what the end goal is other than a second monitor on an "old" system.

Answer (score 10):

I started to wonder if this might actually be possible, if one were to bit-bang the parallel port signals and synthesise VGA signalling.  However, a VGA dot clock is 25.175MHz and a parallel port in ECP mode can transfer 2.5MBPS at best so on the fact of it that's not an option, and even implementing something more complicated, there just isn't enough throughput.

Comment: A special driver and custom hardware, though you'd be limited to lol-frames-per-second (I'd say maybe 6-8?). You're not going to run games on it, but maybe you could run terminal programs or PowerPoint slide shows.

Comment: @phyrfox: There would not be any frames per second rate limit from driving the VGA this way. Rather there would be a very very low horizontal resolution limit of around 64 pixels or so. Otherwise it should work.

Comment: I was thinking more of a custom video card with 2MB of "VRAM"(double buffered) that collects a full 640x480 every 8th of a second or so while keeping the signal for the VGA, but if we're going full custom, anything in between would be possible.

Comment: @phyrfox: At that point you'd just get a cheap Raspberry Pi and connect its GPIO pins to the parallel port. That's more than enough processing power to decompress a simple RLE scheme. The PC driver part will be way harder.

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE *Otherwise it should work.* - While numerically 25 "mega" vs 2.5 "mega" seems like a factor of 10, it's a 8-bit parallel port, so the result is 25 MHz vs 312.5 kHz, a factor of 80. As VGA line frequency is something 31.5 kHz, and ~10% of a scanline is hsync, for playing safe one could output a hsync signal, an empty pixel, 7 actual pixels, and an empty pixel. And even then it's not obvious that the monitor will accept it.

Comment: @tevemadar: In any case, the parallel port output pins can be switched as fast as you can do port IO, which is what I figured the 2.5 Mbps would roughly correspond to. You don't need any ECP mode or bidirectional handshaking. You just hammer on the bitbanging.

Comment: @phyrfox: I would not describe that as "connecting a VGA monitor to a parallel port".

Comment: This doesn't prove it's impossible. It may be possible with really long pixels. But still, why bother trying to make it work?

Comment: Using shift registers and doubling pixels you could get close. Would be monochrome (or very low resolution color) though!

Comment: For a 640 * 480 * 8-bit pixel @60 Hz, we need _up to_ 147,456,000 bits /second.  With "ECP mode can transfer 2.5MBPS", we need to compress images by about a factor of 60.  Quite reasonable to do aside from gaming.

Answer (score 5):

> I have an old system that I want to connect two monitors with. I have only one VGA port

Then install a second video card. PCs have no limit to the number of VGA cards as long as you can find interrupt channels for them.  Driving them is tricky, but Windows can handle that.

It needs the throughput available on the ISA or PCI bus in order to render graphics worth a darn.

I get where you might think that. I just got a new Mac and it has USB-C ports on it. Apparently I can connect additional monitors to the USB-C ports. As well as the scanner, printer, keyboard, anything can go into those USB-C ports.  Darn, you hardly need any other kind of port!

Old computers can't do that.  Any given port did **One Thing**.  Or to be more precise spoke **One Protocol**, you could certainly connect an HP Laserjet III via parallel OR serial OR ethernet.

The parallel port would not have the throughput to do anything useful with a monitor *graphics-wise*.  I suppose you could buy/build a single-board computer that would emulate a printer and drive a VGA monitor.  Be easier to get a thing that emulates a VT100 terminal using a VGA monitor,  but that would work better on the serial port.  You would be able to do VT100 tier graphics on that, but that's pretty lame compared to a VGA card.

Comment: The reason you can connect monitors to your USB-C ports is that the USB-C port is also a video port (DisplayPort), connected to the Mac's graphics card. When a monitor is connected, it switches to DisplayPort mode (with bonus USB). It's still a One Thing Port but it's a Flexible One Thing Port. There might be additional restrictions, like, if  the graphics card can only handle one external monitor but you have 4 ports, you might only be able to mirror.

Comment: Are you sure there is no limit on VGA cards? isn't there some problem with video BIOS conflicts or something? Linux has a special driver to work around something or other problem with overlapping address ranges

Comment: @user253751 There's no *designed-in* limit - nobody at a manufacturer said "Let's deliberately architect the system to lock in only 2 video cards max". But as a practical thing you run out of resources before you get too many. Back in the DOS days, driver and BIOS problems were on you :)

Comment: I read that VGA cards all decode the same address range, so they conflict if there's more than one.

Comment: @user253751 Some have jumpers or DIP switches to let you move them.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have an ISA bus system you can have two video cards, one color card (eg: VGA or EGA or CGA) and one monochrome card (eg MDPA or HGC, or monochrome EGA or VGA)

Answer (score 0):

Or you could buy a "VGA splitter", and put two VGA monitors on the one VGA output.

There are two kinds of VGA splitter: the simplest, which just displayed the same content on two monitors, and the kind at one time used by anybody who wanted a large display, which splits the VGA signal into 2 sections, or 4 or 6 or 16 or whatever, so that you can get a wall of diplay as big as you want.